# Passing data from Android Browser to external app

Tags: android, browser

This is what I need to do:

I have an app running in the background. Now when the user is browsing and comes across an 'interesting' URL, he can make a gesture and send the URL to the external app. The app then processes it.

I can think of two way of doing this(though I am not sure if either is possible)
1. Program something like a hook that senses the particular gesture or key press and sends the URL to the app

1. Write something like an add on to the browser.

My question is, is any of this possible. If yes, could you give me a few hints so that I can go ahead. If not, then is there any other way to do it?

Thanks,
Sandip

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : You can't use the android browser like this.

Long answer : The android browser is an application. The only way you can interact with it is to call it with an argument (a URL). And... that's all. You can't write an extension to the browser like you can do in Chrome.

If you want to control the browser, use a webview, but even in that case, you won't have the ability to detect gesture.

What you're trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading. It should allow you to be notified when a new URL is loaded.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29